# Phone Gap - is it possible to run external *.jar file?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have to integrate my app with code that's put into a jar file - is it possible to establish communication between phonegap and *.jar file so I can run some methods from this file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are really two parts to this question.

First you can create a phonegap plugin to interact with custom java code.  In your case this would be "glue" for using the jar.

Second, you need to either add the jar to your project if it is available at compile time so that it gets included in the build, or if it is only available at run time (and contains compiled dex classes, rather than portable java ones) you load it with a dex class loader and call into it with reflection.  But If it is a random jar for desktop use you won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

You can register callbacks in the Android PhoneGap Activity code so that a javascript call in your JS can call out to your custom Java code from your own jar or just compiled in java code in the Android app.

You can do this as a one off hack in your Android Activity code, or you could just write a [PhoneGap plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android)